# How to get my login form to automatically align to the right?

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a top menu bar with a login form on it. The login form is all the way on the left but moved in about 300px. How can I get it so the login form aligns automatically to the right and adjusts when you resize the window? Here is the code I have right now:

```
#topbar {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: #336680;
    box-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#login-form {
    min-width: 520px;
    top: 0.3em;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Oh and here is the html that I have for this section:

```
<form id="login-form" action="action">
  <div>
    <input type="email" id="login-email" />
    <input type="password" id="login-password" />
    <input type="submit" class= "btn btn-info" id="login-button" value="Sign in" />
  </div>
</form>

<div id="topbar">
</div>
```

Comment: Where html code ? and better if you create some fiddle. Thanks.

Comment: Seconded. Create a fiddle with HTML, otherwise nobody can actually help you.

Comment: How do I create a fiddle?

Comment: Just a simple tip: usually design the html in a way that your elements are already where they should be... in other words. The top bar should be above the form. Don't use CSS and position absolutes to put things anywhere.

Comment: Go here http://jsfiddle.net/ sign up, paste the necessary html code in html field, css code to css field, save and paste the link to the created fiddle here.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will fix the html to put the topbar first and I will make a fiddle and paste the link.

Comment: Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/5AMWE5T/6HsMC/

Comment: Am I missing something? Just `float: right;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your form inside the `topbar`. Add `text-align:right` on `topbar`. Then set `100%` width for login form.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8e8q7/)

Or you can use `right` as well:

```
#login-form {
    top: 0.3em;
    right: 0.3em;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8e8q7/2/)

Or `float: right`, its up to you:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8e8q7/3/)

HTML:

```
<div id="topbar">
    <form id="login-form" action="action">
        <div>
            <input type="email" id="login-email" />
            <input type="password" id="login-password" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="login-button" value="Sign in" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

## topbar {

```
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0.5;
background-color: #336680;
box-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: right;
```

}

## login-form {

```
width: 100%;
top: 0.3em;
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
```

}